# If A -> B is augmented with C, is AC -> B legal?

Tags: relational-theory, dependencies

Given the augmentation axiom and the decomposition axioms of [functional dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) and a relation of R(A,B,C) with an FD of:
A -> B

I can augment A -> B with C to get AC -> BC.

Can I then decompose AC -> BC to get AC -> B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Yes. You can decompose to get `AC -> B` and `AC -> C`.